# why closing down the primary doesn't make replica to vote a new primary in mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

I am experimenting the mongodb replica set, in which I started localhost:27017 as secondary and localhost:27018 as primary.

then I disconnect the localhost:27018, and I expected localhost:27017 to automatically become a primary, but it doesn't work as expected.  In the shell, using command like rs.add() or rs.remove() gives out a error like '        **"errmsg" : "replSetReconfig command must be sent to the current replica set primary.**",'

I know this error is because the command is now running in the secondary, but since the primary is closed down already. what steps I should do now?

And also why closing down the primary doesn't allow the replica set to vote for a new primary ? what is the flexible way to make it automatic vote for a new primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elect a new primary in MongoDB replica set the majority of the members must vote for the new primary.  That's majority of the original (or configured) members.

You configured two members - one is not a majority.  You need to add a third member, either a regular node or an arbiter, if you want your failover to happen automatically.

Comment: when I closed down the primary or secondary, on the data folder there are files , local.0 , local.1 , local.ns. Are they the journal files ?

Comment: That's the oplog - like a transaction log. Journal is in the journal sub directory.